# how to install c++ library libuv on OS X?

Tags: c++, libevent, libuv

i want to install libuv on OS X,but when i

```
brew install libuv
```

then i write a simple demo :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uv.h>
int main() {
    uv_loop_t *loop = uv_loop_new();
    printf(“Now quitting.\n”);
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
    return 0;
 }
```

always error:

```
main.cc:2:10: fatal error: 'uv.h' file not found
#include <uv.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What command did you use to compile? It appears that on recent OS X version (due to Xcode?) you need to add `-I/usr/local/include` to the compiler flag.

Answer (score 0):

Answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258794/libraries-to-compile-libuv-on-os-x) may help you...

```
$ g++ -luv main.cc
```

Or

```
$ g++ -o main main.cc build/Release/libuv.a -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes : `-I/usr/local/include` helped me.
But one point add this compiler flags not in project but in sdk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Xcode you can add libuv as a Git submodule (`git submodule add https://github.com/libuv/libuv Externals/libuv`) and use GYP to generate an xcodeproj for libuv (as explained in libuv's README) and add this xcodeproj to your main Xcode project.

It can be automated (for easy updating) with a simple shell script (assumes you put the libuv submodule in `Externals/libuv`, but can be changed):

```
git submodule update --init
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp.git Externals/libuv/build/gyp
Externals/libuv/gyp_uv.py -f xcode
```

Then you'll be able to add libuv as a dependency and to the libraries to link your target to:

[image: Xcode configuration]

The last thing to do is to tell Xcode where are libuv's headers:

[image: Headers configuration]

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30650931/linking-libuv-library-in-xcode/38998048#38998048)